# Camera crashes after taking picture and hitting ok

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I am developing an app which sends an intent to take a picture. I am using a Galaxy S5 but this problem is confirmed on 3 different devices.

First the camera started doing a loop where hitting OK just returned back to take another photo. I refactored  the code and fixed that problem but had others. Now, after bringing up the take photo screen, using the back button goes back successfully and hitting retry after taking the photo works fine. However hitting OK does one of three things:

- Works (~%20)
- throws an error *outside* my own error handler.
  "Unfortunately MyApp has stopped unexpectedly". Then it goes back to the calling activity, throwing an error from my handler because now it is trying to read from something which is now null (presumably because the app crashed). Breakpoints are now ignored and I have to launch debug again. I can go back to first page of app and go through process again, but debug doesn't respond. (~30%)
- Same as before except my error is thrown, I click the back button to get rid of it then the back button to go back a screen and then I get the "Unfortunately myApp has stopped". (~50%)

I have **not** been able to find the error being thrown from the camera which causes the initial weirdness and then causes everything to crash. I have a breakpoint on onActivityResult which is never triggered if an error is thrown. Also my catch block on `startActivityForResult` never throws that error. The errors always come from NPE's in the onCreate as the activity tries to start up again after the photo is taken or the app throwing the "Unfortunately myApp has stopped".

I have a ton more detail but I don't want to overload with info. Basically when I hit OK it either works ~20% of the time or all hell breaks loose the other 80% of the time. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why the results are so seemingly random and unpredictable? Thanks!

I have been following this tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

**callingActivity**

```
 private class SetCounterActivityMenu implements OnMenuItemClickListener {
  private FieldAppActivity a;
  private SetCounterActivityMenu(FieldAppActivity _a) {
    this.a = _a;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem view) {
    switch (view.getItemId()) {
    case 777771: {
      try{
        //nextActivity(CameraActivityNative.class);
        cameraAN = new CameraActivityNative(handler,SetCounterActivity.this);
        Intent intent = cameraAN.getPictureIntent();
        startActivityForResult(intent, cameraAN.CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
      }
      catch (Exception ex){
        handler.error("Error occured taking picture", ex);
      }
      break;
    }
    case 777772: {
      a.showMap(MapShowsWhat.survey);
      break;
    }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

**CameraActivityNative.java**

```
public Intent getPictureIntent() {
    // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // create a file to save the image
    try {
      fileUri = createMultimediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE, handler);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
      Utils.log("Camera Activity Native", "cannot create file", 'e');
    }
    // set the image file name
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    // start the image Intent
    return intent;
  }
private Uri createMultimediaFile(int type,    FieldApplicationManager.FAMEventHandler handler) throws   UnsupportedOperationException, IOException{
// To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
// using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

  File mediaStorageDir = new   File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyDir");

  // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
  if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
    if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
      Utils.log("CameraActivityNative", "failed to create directory", 'd');
      return null;
    }
  }

  // Create a media file name
  String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
  String imageFileName;

  String fileSuffix;
  if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
    imageFileName = "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg";
  }
  else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
    imageFileName = "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4";
  }
  else {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Media type not supported");
  }

  File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir, imageFileName);

  // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
  // galleryAddPic("file:" + mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
  return Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
}
```

Logcat error. I'm not sure this is actually relevant as this is the error that is thrown after the camera has already crashed.

```
02-27 17:56:27.609  17153-17153/android.fieldteam E/ERROR﹕ Message: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String android.api.CountSurvey.stationid' on a null object reference
    Last System Info: null
    Parameter: onGCFCreate
    Stack Trace: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String android.api.CountSurvey.stationid' on a null object reference
            at android.gui.SetCounterActivity.onGCFCreate(SetCounterActivity.java:33)
            at android.gui.FieldAppActivity.onCreate(FieldAppActivity.java:64)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2728)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5837)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could paste the stack trace from the logcat.

Comment: It is hard to get an idea of the structure of your code, as most of the code you have posted exist outside of methods. Can you please post your code as being part of their correct methods and callbacks?

Comment: I have added it. Unfortunately I have not been able to find the stacktrace coming from the camera itself.

Comment: Sorry about that I think everything is in its respective method now

Comment: That exception is in `SetCounterActivity` and I bet line 33 is your setContentView. This looks like a problem with your xml configuration. Can you show those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I apologize for not being more clear in asking this question as I wasn't really sure myself. It turned out being multiple problems at once which I mistakenly took to all be the same problem. Hopefully this will help someone else out in the future. Here is a summary of the problems I faced

1. Whenever the it returned from the camera intent the debugger was
   detaching (I thought this was because of an error from the camera
   but turns out to be somewhat normal)

   - Fix: Force debugger to wait and reconnect
     [Debugger disconnects when calling external intent (camera)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056661/debugger-disconnects-when-calling-external-intent-camera)
2. When returning from the camera intent sometimes the app was being destroyed by the operating system (I'm assuming for memory
   reasons). This resulted in sporadic behavior and my state object
   would have several null fields upon returning, making my app crash.

   - Fix: Write state object to file before sending picture, load in my    parent activity class which handles onCreate then goes to
     the subclassed activity.
3. When the app was destroyed, onCreate was called then onActivityResult as opposed to just calling onActivityResult when the app is not destroyed. This caused weird behavior as I was calling the camera intent from on create.

   - Fix: put a check if savedInstanceState was null to check if the activity had previous data and if it did not it would launch the camera. This fixed the problem where sometimes it would get stuck in an endless loop of taking pictures and returning to the camera.
4. As a result of the other problems, errors were not always seen in my normal error toast or in my log (from the debugger sometimes detaching) this made it much harder to debug since it was inconsistent.

   - Same as #1.

Comment: Re #2: this issue was discussed here before, and nice code samples were provided.

Comment: I'll add to this that I had a very similar issue (at least, I had points #2, #3 and #4 happen), and simply restarting the phone fixed almost everything. Apparently, something was up with the camera app.